# Was Ecuador govenrment already warned about inadmissibility of force using agains protesters?

Tags: human-rights, protests, police, ecuador, south-america

As heard today, there is a civil standoff between military/police and protesters in Ecuador(some sources : [1](https://thegrayzone.com/2019/10/07/ecuador-revolt-lenin-morenos-neoliberal-drone-zangano/), [2](https://morningstaronline.co.uk/article/w/farmers-and-indigenous-rights-groups-block-roads-and-march-ecuadors-capital)). Origin of protests(possibly) was implementing IMF economic recommendations, including reducing social subsidies.

On the most of photo/video materials, there can be seen excessive use of force from the police and military. But I haven't found mainstream media articles about that, no HRW warnings also. Even US Department of State is silent.

Did I miss it, or there is no warnings from human rights organisations?